# How can I use Electron without having X11?

Tags: electron, embedded-linux, x11, framebuffer, wayland

I'm trying to run an application that uses Electron on my Embedded System.

The problem is that Electron has dependecies with it but i can only use wayland or frame buffer instead of X11.

Can anyone help me?

Andrea

Comment: Sadly, as also written [in this issue on GitHub](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/9056), Electron currently depends on X11 and cannot run on Wayland. It might in the future, once Chrome gets Wayland support. (But as Electron doesn't use the newest Chrome version available, that will take a *while*...)

Comment: It's impossible also using framebuffer? It's strictly necessary X11

Comment: As far as I know, and as far as that GitHub issue goes: yes, X11 is currently the only posibility.

Comment: Thank you for the info I saw that someone in 2017 was trying to use wayland but they hadn't pot anything new and I hoped someone found a solution but I think they didn't

Comment: Is it possible for you to run a virtual X11 server, `xvfb`, as the display, then copy it with `xvnc`, then view that in a browser in wayland using `novnc`? Or of course, you can have an X server on a remote machine and use X11 over the network.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't really answer your question, but maybe you can use Xwayland? It will set up a X11 server that acts as a Wayland client, which your electron app can connect to.

Comment: Yes i could use Xwayland but don't know how

Answer (score 0):

Try it like that

```
electron --enable-features=UseOzonePlatform --ozone-platform=wayland
```

further details can be found here: [How to run Electron apps like Slack etc for Wayland?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63187542/how-to-run-electron-apps-like-slack-etc-for-wayland)

However, I found for myself that Electron requires a lot of dependencies (try it with `ldd electron`). It requires X11 dependencies although the arguments above are considered.

Comment: is there any change in this now? I tried cross-compiling an Electron app for arm64 device with Wayland only and it obviously didnt work because it links to a ton of X11 libraries like libXrandr which aren't present on a native wayland system, and I'd rather not have them there either. Chromium works fine though. `libX11.so.6 => not found
` `libXcomposite.so.1 => not found` `libXdamage.so.1 => not found`

Comment: unfortunately I am not aware of  any change to this