# How to run Electron apps like Slack etc for Wayland?

Tags: electron, wayland

It seems that Electron has not support Wayland yet.

About Electron issue: [Consider providing a build for Wayland](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/10915)

Does anybody know how to compile Electron to support Wayland native? (step by step)
and run Electron apps in Wayland(Weston etc...).

It took hours to compile electron and I fail many times.

Answer (score 10):

Initial Wayland support was merged in [Electron 12](https://github.com/electron/electron/pull/26022).

There is nothing specifically about it in the release notes
but it can be tested with a recent electron version by running:

```
/path/to/yourElectronApplication --enable-features=UseOzonePlatform --ozone-platform=wayland
```

If you're using flatpack and your Electron application is Slack you need to create an override to expose the wayland socket as well as  setting the GDK_BACKEND env variable to wayland.
The override will be permanently stored in ~/.local/share/flatpak/overrides

```
flatpak override --user --socket=wayland com.slack.Slack
GDK_BACKEND=wayland flatpak run com.slack.Slack --enable-features=UseOzonePlatform --ozone-platform=wayland
```